# Eclipse - How to select the Java methods to compile when building the Jar file?

Tags: java, eclipse, security, jar

I have finished a Java project in Eclipse and i want to export 2 Jar versions for it. One is a Trial version and the other is a Pro version.

Is there a way in Eclipse to command it to build the Jar using specific classes or methods for the Trial version and when building the Pro version use other classes or methods?

What i'm trying to do is omitting some code in the Trial version to make it secure and prevent it from being hacked as it has happened before in one of my programs.

Answer (score 0):

The method I'd try first would be to shell script this. You can then invoke the scripts using "External Commands" in Eclipse. Thus, you can hook-up your scripts in to Eclipse there.

Going a few thousand steps further, if you use something like github (or gitlab, like me) you can setup the CI tools to run such scripts for you too.

Anyway, there may be better methods, this is what I'd start with based on what I personally know. I've had good success with my own shell scripts invoked by Eclipse. But you may have different needs.